# Find a specific value/characters in a string field (If statement)

Tags: javascript

I have these string statments:

- 10 - Holiday Booking
- 20 - Summer term
- 34 - Nighttime
- Autumn time

I wanted to create a IF statement which says:

If the start of the string contains 'X - ' (a number and a hyphen with spaces, although I think it will recognise the number as a string type), then keep it as it is, otherwise add a random number and hyphen to the start

- 10 - Holiday Booking
- 20 - Summer term
- 34 - Nighttime
- 55 - Autumn time

I am using Google App Scripts/Java.

Comment: Does the random number have to be _unique_ from the leading numbers which already appear in your text?

Comment: You might want to have a look at what a RegExp is and how to use it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, except for @Yuri who is completely insensitive and ignorant. I got covid on Friday and have only just been able to look at my phone. I will review your comments as soon as I am able to function again. Once again, thank you @ Andy, @ Tim and @ Secan for being patient with me. Im also not a guy @ Yuri.

Comment: I'm sorry if you got sick. It changes the matter. I've removed my comment. Get well.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I didn't realise this was similar to a question I had asked separately (I am VERY new to coding/python/stack!)  @secan thanks for the links to the regex script they were very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
yourArrayOfStrings.map(e => /^\d*\s-\s/.test(e) ? e : `${Math.floor(Math.random()*100)} - ${e}`);
```

- `Array.prototoype.map(e => ...)` loop over array and return modified element
- Regex: `/^\d*\s-\s/` - checks if string starts with number - ...

```js
const strings = ["10 - Holiday Booking", "20 - Summer term", "34 - Nighttime", "Autumn time"];

const res = strings.map(e => /^\d*\s-\s/.test(e) ? e : `${Math.floor(Math.random()*100)} - ${e}`);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you @jns for the explanations! That was very useful! I can see you included Math.random which I assume generates the random number, in my script I will be looking to create the numbers sequentially (i.e. the largest number +1) but I think I can do this bit myself!

Answer (score 0):

The function can be made like this

```
const str1 = '10 - Holiday Booking';
const str2 = 'Autumn time';

function MyFun(str) {
  const firstAscii = str.charCodeAt(0);
  if( (firstAscii>=65 && firstAscii<=90 ) || (firstAscii>=65 && firstAscii<=90) ){
    str = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + " - " + str;
  }
  console.log(str);
}

MyFun(str1);
MyFun(str2);
```